# PreSignedPost In AWS SDK for .NET for Presigned Urls

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

In python aws sdk `boto3`, there is a method called `generate_presigned_post` which returns a dictionary instead of a simple url.

I am looking for an equivalent method in the `dotnet` client, But all I could find was 2 methods, `GeneratePreSignedURL` & `GetPreSignedURL`, which both returns a string url.

I wanted to confirm if there is any equivalent method in dotnet client for `generate_presigned_post` or if we could somehow replicate its functionality in dotnet library.

Comment: What's the advantage of the "dictionary" as opposed to the string?

Answer (score 0):

```
using Amazon.S3;
AmazonS3Client _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(<credentials>);
var preSignedUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
{
    BucketName = configS3Bucket,
    Key = keyName,
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2),
    Protocol = (Protocol.HTTPS),
    Verb = verb,
    
};
String PresignedURL = _s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(preSignedUrlRequest);
byte[] data = <get your file data>;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
    var r = await client.PutAsync(PresignedURL, content);
}
```